# Entity Framework Core console app - database connection generates ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have created a console app and I need to use Entity Framework Core for some database transactions, however it's not working when I run my app.

This is my `DbContext` class:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext ()
    {
    }

    public MyDbContext (DbContextOptions<MyDbContext > options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<MyUsers> MyUser{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbConnectionString"]);
        }
    }
}
```

My `app.config`:

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
       <add key="DbConnectionString" value= "myconnectionstring" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

This is how I am calling it:

```
  MyDbContext _context = new MyDbContext();

  var user = _context.MyUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);
```

When I run `add-migration` in console, I get the following error:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
```

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)   at ReGeneratePassword.EntityFrameWorkFiles.MyDbContext .OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) in C:\Dev\test\ReGeneratePassword\EntityFrameWorkFiles\MyDbContext.cs:line 40   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)

Comment: what do you mean could you provide details

Comment: Remove both constructors.

Comment: I did its not working

Comment: Show your code, it still has constructors above.

Answer (score 0):

How does your **appsettings.json** look? Have you added your connection string there? Is it the right name? Becuase it says the parameter **"connectionString"** is **null**. So maybe you either have the **wrong name** for it or you havent **added** your connection string like this in appsettings.json which is where your saying its coming from by this ->

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbConnectionString"]);
```

Your appsettings.json should look something like this

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Connection": "server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;database=TimeReport.API;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
```

Comment: Yes ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbConnectionString"] is set in App.Config and its comming and its not null

Comment: I added my App.Config code too

Comment: its a console app, not ASP.Net core

Comment: What nugget packages do you have installed? Do you have ->
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlserver ?
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools ?

Comment: Yes, I did both here is the list: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design ?